# Alternatives to Qt.escape in PySide?

Tags: python, xml, qt, pyqt, pyside

I am porting some code from PyQt to PySide, which includes a home-grown XML exporter. The code is peppered with lines like:

```
Qt.escape(textNote)
```

This is new to me. My PyQt book (Summerfield, 2008) writes:

> The Qt.escape() function takes a QString and returns it with any XML
>   [metacharacters properly escaped](https://wiki.python.org/moin/EscapingXml). And we...convert any
>   paragraph and line breaks in the notes to their Unicode equivalents.

But unfortunately for my goal of creating XML from text, `escape` seems to no longer be in use.

This issue is discussed at two sources I found:

http://qt-project.org/wiki/Transition_from_Qt_4.x_to_Qt5#f166611e9788f9dbdff69088d622663e

http://www.kdab.com/automated-porting-from-qt-4-to-qt-5/

Unfortunately, they both suggest to use `QString.toHtmlEscaped()` but this method seems to not exist in PySide (indeed, QString is not part of PySide's lexicon).

Finally, as of four years ago, it seemed `escape` is not something that they intended to support in PySide, [as discussed at a bug report](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-bz-archive/229.html):

> After a discussion with other PySide developers, we decided not export
>   this function, the reasons are:
>
> - This function is part of QtGui, if we create a QtGui.Qt, this will cause some headaches with QtCore.Qt.
> - PyQt4 also didn't export this function.
> - There are functions in python std lib that you can use to achieve the same goals, like xml.sax.saxutils.escape().
>
> So, I'll mark this bug as WONTFIX.

This *seems* to answer my question, but it is four years old, and I am curious if it still holds. That is, is there no PySide escape functionality, so is the best option to go to `saxutils`? Or perhaps is there some workaround akin to `toHtmlEscaped` in PySide that I've overlooked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you would have used

```
Qt.escape(yourText)
```

you can get the exact same functionality with

```
from xml.sax.saxutils import escape as escape
escape(yourText)
```

It's a little less elegant, but it works. The PySide developers have remained consistent with their [initial reaction to a question](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-bz-archive/229.html) about this four years ago.